# Excel - 2-way lookup with different row count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I need a nested `for` loop **without** using VBA.

I'm not sure how to use `index` and `match` for this.

Dashboard sheet - Key:

- **Blue ID** is the ID number of the user
- **Red ID** is the key of the field `uit`
- **Green Value**  is the number that should be there

[image]

Dataset sheet - This is the dataset that I get:

[image]

The first parameter of `index` is the dataset. If the dataset was only 7 rows then it wouldn't be a problem. The problem is that because it is bigger and repeated multiple times, the number 265000 comes with it.

Goal: get the **Green Value** field from `Dataset sheet` on to the `Dashboard Sheet` and use **Blue ID** and **Red ID** to filter

Edit:  This is the file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=35389656981540084385
I have traid with sumproduct the only problem is that i need to add the `ID`**Blue** number before 265000 **dark red**. But that isn't the solution because i need to copy every `ID`**Blue**  and past it before `uit`

Comment: Can you explain logic, how `3001,00` and `2501,00` are coming in 3rd image? Also explain what are the other values in column `E`. How they are related with result highlighted as green?

Comment: ? owke..  dataset table is data that came from a export of a application.. the other values are not related in `E`.  They are there to show you that every datablock (image: row1-row7 , row8-row15) have different row nummer. You can't do get-row-index(10010) + 5 = 6 and get the value of `E`. The **Red** is juist ID number..

Comment: Still it is not clear to me what actually you want to do? What is manual calculation to get `3001,00`?

Comment: **blue ID** of the dasboard look in to the dataset `A`  column.. when i found it (say `10010`) he count the rows till the next nummer `10034` that is 6 rows.
The dataset should be `a:7 - e:7`..
**red KeyID** look in the dataset `a:7 - e:7`for the number 265000
then copy the green value.
past the green value in the greenfield of dashboard...
3001,00 it's just a number no calcucation nothing it's just plain text output of a application..

Comment: @Janis I think your best bet is to copy that **Blue ID** down so you can use that `SUMPRODUCT`.  If it truly needs to be a "Dashboard UI", you can use conditional formatting to "white out" the numbers in column `A` if they're the same as the next number.  Something like `=$A1<>$A2` applied to `=$A:$A`.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate solution:**

1. Select entire colum A and B
2. Press F5 or Ctrl + G
3. Click Special
4. Select Blanks and hit "Ok"
5. Press "=" sign
6. Press Up arrow on keyboard
7. Press Ctrl + Enter
8. Use =INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,(A:A=BlueID)*(D:D=RedID),0)) to get the answer

Try and let me know if it works.